# How to find width on components in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Html:

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-style">
  <tabs
    v-for="tabelement in tabelements" :name="tabelement":tabselected="tabelement == type ?  'active': ''" v-on:click="tabclick(tab)"
  ></tabs>
</ul>
```

JS:

```js
Vue.component('tabs', {
  template:'<li :class="tabselected"><a href="#">{{name}}</a></li>',
  props:['name','tabselected']
});
```

I want to find the sum of width of all `li` in this example.

Comment: is it horizontal tab panel?

Comment: yes it is horizontal tab

Comment: so u need ul's width, dont you? [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vjvMp/1498/)

Comment: i think this will help. thanks

Comment: Is there any way i can loop through each li. get it individual width

Comment: When do u need widths? on method?

Comment: The li are dynamic so i cant find the width by the method in above jsFiddle  .my requirement is to achieve a horizontal scroll if the ul width is larger than container width. the scroll action is done on click on two arrow buttons. the scroll length must be equal to next hidden tab width.

Answer (score 5):

Add watch block to your script.

**script**

```js
watch: {
 'tabelements': function(val) {
   var lis = this.$refs.ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
   for (var i = 0, len = lis.length; i < len; i++) {
     console.log(lis[i].clientWidth); // do something
   }
   console.log(this.$refs.ul.clientWidth, this.$refs.ul.scrollWidth);
 }
}
```

if scrollWidth > clientWidth, u can show your arrows.

Updated. Explain [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k0ht01tj/17/)

**template**

```html
<tabs ref="ul">
```

Put ref on component otherwise instance doesnot know about it

**script**

`this.$nextTick`
This function run method when dom is updated

Comment: it is not working for me . can you show it in this https://jsfiddle.net/k0ht01tj/